# Populating a database in django and retrieving the values in the view gives error becaue of ForeignKey?

Tags: django, model

I am using a script to populate the model database in django, but there seems to be a problem because of the foreignKey relationship.

The populating script seems to work fine but after I try to access the page it gives an error:

```
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    Week matching query does not exist.
```

Populating script:

```
    def add_week(week):
        w = Week.objects.get_or_create(date=week)
        return w

    def add_song(name, artist, position, week):
        s = week.song_set.get_or_create(name=name, artist=artist, position=position)
        return s

    this_week = (add_week(week=soup.time.text))[0]

    for position, (song_name, artist) in enumerate(chart):
        print "%d. %s - %s" % (position+1, song_name, artist)
        add_song(name=song_name, artist=artist, position=position+1, week=this_week)
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Week(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.date

class Song(models.Model):
    week = models.ForeignKey(Week, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    position = models.SmallIntegerField()
    difference = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from charts.models import Song, Week

# Create your views here.
def chart(request):
    songs = Song.objects.order_by('position')
    week = Week.objects.get(pk=1)  #here comes the error, even though I see two weeks in admin view

def changed_since_last_week(request):
    week = Week.objects.get(pk=5)
    last_week = Week.objects.get(pk=6)
    songs = Song.objects.filter(week=week).order_by('position')
    songs_last_week = Song.objects.filter(week=last_week)
    context_dict = {'songs_last_week': songs}
    for song in songs:
        song_last= Song.objects.all().filter(name=song.name)
        if song_last:
           song.objects.difference = song_last.position - song.position
    return render(request, 'charts/change.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: If you look at the url in your admin view, is the primary key of the two weeks in the database really 1 (and 2)?

Comment: @sthzg You are the man. Do you happen to know how to change it perhaps? The pk, I mean?

Comment: Now it gives me:   

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'position'

Comment: In general, you don't. The primary key of a database record is generated by your database and is an automatically incrementing integer. So, hard-coding a ``get()`` by a particular ``pk`` is rather unusual, if you want a specific record you could query by each of the model's fields, e.g. ``Week.objects.get(date='my_hardcoded_date')``.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Do you happen to know why I can't access the position like I do in the view with song.position. It gives me the error:'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'position'.
You can write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the original answer. Regarding the queryset: your variable contains a queryset rather than a single model instance. To get to your model instance(s), either use ``myvar[0].position`` or loop over all instances in the queryset with ``for my_instance in myvar: print my_instance.position``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the url in your admin view, are the primary keys of the two weeks in the database really 1 (and 2)? It is possible that if you tested the generating script more than once (or maybe played with the database before) the two records just happen to have other primary keys than 1 (or 2).

Also, if you want a specific record you could query by each of the model's fields, e.g. `Week.objects.get(date='my_hardcoded_date')`. (by the way, I guess the value in `date` is something customized, so that you can't use one of Django's native `DateField` or `DateTimeField`).